# ReactiveMongo - getting latest document in collection?

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0

I've probably missed something obvious, but within the ReactiveMongo API (v0.8) how do you set a limit on the number of documents returned by a query?

I'd like to return the single most recent document added to a collection. This is my code so far:

```
def getLatest()(implicit reader: reactivemongo.bson.handlers.RawBSONReader[T]):     Future[Option[T]] = {
    collection.find (QueryBuilder(
        queryDoc = Some(BSONDocument()),
        sortDoc = Some(BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONInteger(-1)))
    )).headOption().mapTo[Option[T]]
}
```

headOption() works to retrieve a single result, but I'm not explicitly using any kind of Mongo limit clause so I'm worried about this query's impact on the DB. Please help me improve this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 0.8 you have to set the `batchSize` option to `1` in order to tell MongoDB to close the database cursor automatically:

```
val maybedoc = collection.find(BSONDocument(), QueryOpts().batchSize(1)).headOption
// or using QueryBuilder like you do
val maybedoc2 = collection.find (QueryBuilder(
    queryDoc = Some(BSONDocument()),
    sortDoc = Some(BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONInteger(-1)))
), QueryOpts().batchSize(1)).headOption()
```

In 0.9 collections have been refactored and greatly simplified. Now you can do this:

```
val maybedoc = collection.
                 find(BSONDocument()).
                 sort(BSONDocument("_id" -> -1)).
                 one[BSONDocument]
```

The `one[T]` method in 0.9 sets the batchSize flag for you and returns an `Option[T]`.

Comment: In which file is the new one[T] method defined Stephane? I found it with autocomplete when upgrading, but would like to peruse the source :)

Comment: It is defined here: https://github.com/zenexity/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/api/collections/genericcollection.scala#L355 :) You can checkout the updated [scaladoc](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.9/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.default.BSONQueryBuilder).

Comment: Thanks - I guess it has to add the options to the query document before working with the cursor. What would be an exmaple then of a regular headOption without batchsize? Are you able to keep calling headOption on the same cursor? And sorry for answering just before you!

Comment: You don't have to be sorry ^^ Actually I'm very glad to see the community at work :) You're right about `headOption` – it is pretty much useless now that there is `one` which is now the natural and efficient way to fetch at most one document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the headOption() function limits the query to just one result:

```
def headOption()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) :Future[Option[T]] = {
  collect[Iterable](1).map(_.headOption)
}
```

https://github.com/zenexity/ReactiveMongo/blob/0.8/src/main/scala/api/cursor.scala#L180

Comment: Does that definitely perform a row-limited query on the DB side, or does it just take the first result from the cursor? I'm curious to know if the underlying Mongo DB might be doing unnecessary work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think it does actually. I just tested a simple example and set db.setProfilingLevel(2) in the mongo shell. The resulting query contains "ntoreturn" : 0 (which if your find query does not limit to a unique index, will return the default limit, probably 20). Adding "QueryOpts().batchSize(1)" as the second parameter to the find function fixes this :) well spotted! For the most part, I was only using headOption with unique indexes. It'll be interesting to see how 0.9 handles this.